# id command is not showing secondary groups

Tags: centos, openldap, sssd, nsswitch.conf

During some days I've been working on a LDAP integration. Now, after configure almost everything that I needed, I came up with this last wall: The need of use secondary groups which are taken from the LDAP server.

**Behaviour:**

```
[root@sr-servicesLin ~]# id hmr
uid=2956(hmr) gid=10000(ldapusers) groups=10000(ldapusers)

[root@sr-servicesLin ~]# getent group repo
repo:*:25958:

[root@sr-servicesLin ~]# groups hmr
hmr : ldapusers
```

*Content of repo group (it's a LDAP group):*

```
[root@sr-dns ~]# ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap.eibind.iss -b "dc=eibind,dc=iss" "(&(objectclass=posixGroup)(cn=repo)(gidNumber=*))"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=eibind,dc=iss> with scope subtree
# filter: (&(objectclass=posixGroup)(cn=repo)(gidNumber=*))
# requesting: ALL
#

# repo, Groups, eibind.iss
dn: cn=repo,ou=Groups,dc=eibind,dc=iss
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
cn: repo
memberUid: hmr
memberUid: jcontreras
memberUid: hectoriss
gidNumber: 25958

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success
```

**The scenario:**

OS: Centos 6.7

*Packages:*
· ldap running with ssl
· sssd installed
· nss-pam-ldapd

The problem is:

When I use `id` command I'm not getting the secondary groups of every user, just the principal one (which comes from LDAP, so there is a connection).

I'm going to paste the main config files, I think that I put everything in the correct place. Surfing between sites, I read that is not recommended to have sssd and nsswitch configured at the same time, like configure `ldap` and `sss` for "parse" all the desired data from the server, that it could be a mess for the server or something like that. Despite of this, I wrote ldap and sss as a data sources.

**nsswitch.conf**

```
#
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#

passwd:     files ldap sss
shadow:     files ldap sss
group:      files ldap sss

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files ldap sss

netgroup:   files ldap sss

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files ldap sss
aliases:    files ldap nisplus
```

As you can see, I'm asking to ldap and sss (sssd) about the passwd, shadow and groups. Combined with this config, I also have the sssd.conf file, which is the following:

**sssd.conf**

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, autofs
domains = default

[nss]
filter_users = root,ldap,named,avahi,haldaemon,dbus,radiusd,news,nscd

[pam]

[domain/default]
ldap_tls_reqcert = allow
auth_provider = ldap
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
krb5_realm = eibind.iss
ldap_search_base = dc=eibind,dc=iss
ldap_group_member = uniqueMember
id_provider = ldap
ldap_id_use_start_tls = True
chpass_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldaps://ldap.eibind.iss/

#ldap_user_object_class = user
#ldap_group_object_class = group

#ldap_group_search_base = OU=Groups,DC=eibind,DC=iss
#ldap_group_search_scope = one
#ldap_group_object_class = group

ldap_chpass_uri = ldaps://ldap.eibind.iss/
krb5_kdcip = ldap.eibind.iss
cache_credentials = True
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts
entry_cache_timeout = 600
ldap_network_timeout = 3
krb5_server = ldap.eibind.iss
autofs_provider = ldap
[autofs]
```

Here we can see that I'm using `ldap_schema = rfc2307bis` and `ldap_group_member = uniqueMember`.

I say that because I found over the net that I should change `ldap_schema = rfc2307bis` to `ldap_schema = rfc2307` but it still does not work.

Also, there are some commented lines which I previously tried but without success.

To finish, I'm going to paste the **nslcd.conf**. In here I just followed this tutorial: https://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/setup , so my config file is as it comes plus these following lines:

```
# This comment prevents repeated auto-migration of settings.
uri ldap://ldap.eibind.iss/
base dc=eibind,dc=iss
uid nslcd
gid nslcd
```

I have to be missing something, some value, some stupid config. Probably I spend around 3-4 days looking at this, so any help with be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: out of curiosity, does `groups mhr` work?

Comment: @dawud, it just show up the main group. I edited the question adding this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused, your groups use "memberuid: $username", which is RFC2307, so why dooes your config specify rfc2307bis and uniqueMember?

I would propose to use rfc2307 (which is the default) and if that doesn't work, crank up the debugging and see what queries are made towards the LDAP server.

Comment: Oh man, you really save my time. It was too obvious. Thank you all very much, especially to @jhrozek

Answer (score 3):

When you replace the default:

```
ldap_schema = rfc2307
```

with

```
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
```

in your `sssd.conf` file you need to follow the instructions from the [SSSD FAQ](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/FAQ):

> SSSD supports three LDAP schema types: RFC 2307, RFC 2307bis and IPA (the last being an extension of RFC 2307bis including memberOf backlinks).
>
> By default, SSSD will use the more common RFC 2307 schema. The difference between RFC 2307 and RFC 2307bis is the way which group membership is stored in the LDAP server. In an RFC 2307 server, group members are stored as the multi-valued attribute `memberuid` which contains the name of the users that are members. In an RFC2307bis server, group members are stored as the multi-valued attribute member (or sometimes `uniqueMember`) which contains the DN of the user or group that is a member of this group. RFC2307bis allows nested groups to be maintained as well.
>
> So the first thing to try when you hit this situation is to try setting `ldap_schema = rfc2307bis`, deleting `/var/lib/sss/db/cache_DOMAINNAME.ldb` and restarting SSSD. If that still doesn't work, add `ldap_group_member = uniqueMember`, delete the cache and restart once more. If that still doesn't work, it's time to ​file a bug.

Comment: He lives Whoop :)

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I already tried before post this question.

Comment: Please check my last edit.

Comment: By default is `ldap_scheme=  rfc2307bis`. I also deleted caches after modifications but it still not working properly. Btw, thank you very much for your dedication. @dawud